# Is it legal to distribute customized Ubuntu with non-canonical apps and os x like gui?

Tags: macosx, custom-distributions, legal

Is it legal to distribute customized Ubuntu with preinstalled apps Google Chrome,wine, Skype, Deluge,WPS Office, playonlinux,steam and noobslab.com macbuntu theme?

Comment: Is it even legal for you to agree to any license in your country?

Comment: In Ukraine? Yes. Just say me can I publish it without copyright infringement .Should I
 specify the license agreement of pre-installed software on the custom Ubuntu build page?

Comment: Well, we can't provide you legal advice here on Ask Ubuntu. Since you can enter into legal agreements yourself, you should contact a lawyer in your country.

Comment: Muru is right, we technically cannot offer legal advice. We're technical community, not legal one.  I tried in my answer to explain what I know, but that's as far as it goes. We're not lawyers. But basic idea is that you can distribute Ubuntu.  If you want to also modify it, I'd suggest you try making your own distribution and avoid including proprietary software

Comment: I am a lawyer. I see the only problem with "osx like". You can breach Apple patents with that using their logos and other things. It is hard to tell from what you asked.

Comment: ok, thanks, I change my mind and I will not upload this os x parody.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, if you want to distribute that and call it Ubuntu, then no. You're modifying Ubuntu's base by adding more programs to it. Ubuntu is under GPL license, and GPL [prohibits that in preamble](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html):

> Also, for each author's protection and ours, we want to make certain
>   that everyone understands that there is no warranty for this free
>   software. If the software is modified by someone else and passed on,
>   we want its recipients to know that what they have is not the
>   original, so that any problems introduced by others will not reflect
>   on the original authors' reputations.

You can distribute it, but you cannot call it `Ubuntu` anymore. You have to let the user know you're giving them a modified thing.

Also, you're including `Google Chrome` and `Skype`. These are proprietary, non-open source software. You may want to check if you can distribute these programs along with the modified version of Ubuntu, and I strongly doubt Micro$$oft allows that for Skype

Comment: Thanks, I will call it Macbuntu . I'll take care of distribution when there is free time. And it will be without Google Chrome and Skype.

Comment: @SergeyBogonos *"Macbuntu"* will probably annoy apple *and* ubuntu... if you want to get  "cease and desist" letters you could try calling it "MS-MacBigMac-McUbuntu"

Comment: That is a bit ridiculous  "MS-MacBig. . . " name , but the point is  correct -  Apple and Microsoft have been keen on suing people for most ludicrous reasons. I would suggest thinking about naming more seriously and not rush with it.

Comment: maybe aqualinux . os x gui is aqua. aqua is a good name because it is rare not associated with apple

Comment: Yup, sounds quite good